# Getting no such table: auth_user error and also not able to access the admin page

Tags: django, authentication, blogs

I am trying to add the Django default user creation form for my registration and getting errors. I even removed all my old migration files any solution? Can anyone guide me on how I can fix this?

Settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #third party apps
    'crispy_forms',
    'crispy_tailwind',
    'ckeditor',
    


    #local apps
    #'leads',
    'waqart',
]
```

MODELS.PY

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

MODEL CLASS

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description= RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    main_image= models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True,upload_to='images/')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    item_category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, default='Coding', on_delete=SET_DEFAULT)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True) # new
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

VIEW

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages


# Create your views here.


# Register View


def register (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success (request, f'Account created for {username}!')
            return redirect('waqart-home')

    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error coz, you have not run `python manage.py migrate` command before you run the server.

If you think you have run `python manage.py migrate` before `runserver` commands, then i suspect you have corrupated `migrations` file that needs to be fixed.

Comment: I did those as well even I removed all my old migration files. But I even get the same error when I try to add a super user.

Comment: Please delete your old migrations files, reset your database, and run new makemigrations commands and then migrate. It will surey works

Comment: Thanks what i did is i delete my old migration files as well as the db.sqlite file and it works.